# Getting route for URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

Simple question.  I'm creating links and want to get the route url without hardcoding it.  I know you can use url.content('~/therestofyourlink') but this only goes to the solution route, not the webserver route.

What I want is 'http://localhost/', but localhost could change to anything i.e. the domain name.  I want some code to pick this up so all I need to worry about is the actual link from the webserver route and below.

I'm using MVC razor so any answers using this syntax would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you pointing to content *outside* of your web site?

If not, than using relative urls will be fine. When you deploy the app to production server everything will still work.

If yes, than you need to put the root url in a config (maybe appSettings in web.config).

UPDATE:

If you want to access IIS metabase programmatically than look at [Microsoft.Web.Administation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Please see below for reply as ran out of characters.  Thanks!